# vectorization does not give the same results of for bucle

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, optimization, vectorization

I am trying to optimize my code by using vectorized functions instead of for loops. I have written a function **`s_curves1()`** that takes two inputs, **`t`** and **`x4`**, and returns a value based on certain conditions. I have tested this function using both a for loop and a vectorized version of the function, but the vectorized version is not giving the correct output. I would like to understand why this is happening and how to fix it.

I tried using the **`np.vectorize()`** function to vectorize the **`s_curves1()`** function, and then I tested both versions of the function using the same input values. I was expecting the output of the vectorized function to be equivalent to the output of the original function, but this was not the case. I got the following error message:

```
AssertionError: 
Not equal to tolerance rtol=1e-07, atol=0

Mismatched elements: 6 / 16 (37.5%)
Max absolute difference: 0.48713929
Max relative difference: 0.
 x: array([[0.      , 0.      , 0.      , 0.      ],
       [1.      , 0.176777, 0.06415 , 0.03125 ],
       [1.      , 1.      , 0.362887, 0.176777],
       [1.      , 1.      , 1.      , 0.487139]])
 y: array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

The code I use:

```
def s_curves1(t, x4):
    """
        Unit hydrograph ordinates for UH1 derived from S-curves.
    """
    # Convertir t en un array, si es necesario
    t = np.asarray(t)
    
    # Si t es menor o igual que 0, devolver 0
    if np.any(t <= 0):
        return 0
    # Si t es menor que x4, devolver (t/x4)^2.5
    elif np.any(t < x4):
        return (t/x4)**2.5
    # En cualquier otro caso, devolver 1
    else:
        return 1
# Crear un array de valores para t y x4
t_values = np.array([0, 10, 20, 30])
x4_values = np.array([0, 20, 30, 40])

result1 = np.zeros((len(t_values), len(x4_values)))
# Evaluar la función s_curves1() para cada combinación de t y x4
for i in range(len(t_values)):
    for j in range(len(x4_values)):
        result1[i, j] = s_curves1(t_values[i], x4_values[j])
# Vectorizar la función s_curves1()
vs_curves1 = np.vectorize(s_curves1)

# Evaluar la función vectorizada vs_curves1() para cada combinación de t y x4
result2 = vs_curves1(t_values[:, np.newaxis], x4_values)

# Comprobar que la salida de la función vectorizada es equivalente a la salida de la función original
np.testing.assert_allclose(result1, result2)
```

Comment: `vectorize` has a performance disclaimer.  Did you see that?

Comment: look at the actual results.  Don't just compare them, and run for help when they don't match!

Comment: Is `result2` integer dtype?  You haven't read the `vectorize` docs carefully enough.